# Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 along side windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a windows 10 machine with 750GB hard drive it shows 4 partitions 3 show windows the 4th is blank but when Itry to install ubuntu it wants to wipe out my entire harddrive I must be missing a step. Also I did fdisk -l and it showed the partition 277GB as linux the other 3 as windows how do I tell ubuntu to install on that linux partition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) Additionally, from Windows, you should (1) disable Fast Startup and shutdown Windows and (2) shrink one or more Windows partitions (typically the systems one - C: - and/or the additional data partition) in order to have unallocated space. Then assure you're booting the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode and later choose "install alongside..."

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the guided "Install Alongside Windows" option you need both of the following:

1. You must have enough **unpartitioned free space** for Ubuntu.
2. You must boot the installation media using the same "mode" as Windows is currently installed.  So if Windows is installed as UEFI, you must also boot the USB as UEFI.  This is most common with Windows 10.  If this is a very old Windows installation that has been upgraded several times you might have MBR partitioning. Your BIOS may call this "legacy" or "compatibility".

Comment: Thank you this proved to be the solution

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. This will mark the question as solved.